# Stream generator. Using an iterator in detail

Tags: python, function, loops, iterator, generator

I'm trying to figure out how an iterator works with this example:

There is the function that produces stream generator for given iterable object (list, generator, etc) whose elements contain position and value and sorted by order of apperance.
Stream generator is equal to initial stream (without position), gaps filled with zeroes.

```
from itertools import count

def gen_stream(total, sorted_iterable, extractor=lambda x: x):
    sorted_iterator = iter(sorted_iterable)
    iterable = count() if total is None else range(total)
    try:
        current_extracted_record = extractor(next(sorted_iterator))
    except StopIteration:
        current_extracted_record = None
    for i in iterable:
        if current_extracted_record:
            if i == current_extracted_record[0]:
                try:
                    yield current_extracted_record[1]
                    current_extracted_record = extractor(next(sorted_iterator))
                except StopIteration:
                    current_extracted_record = None
            else:
                yield 0
        else:
            yield 0
```

For example:

```
gen = gen_stream(9,[(4,111),(7,12)])
list(gen) 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 111, 0, 0, 12, 0] # first element has zero index, so 111 located on fifth position, 12 located on 8th position
```

This function also support custom position-value extractor for more advanced cases, e.g.

```
def day_extractor(x):
    months = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    acc = sum(months[:x[1] - 1]) + x[0] - 1
    return acc, x[2]
```

```
precipitation_days = [(3,1,4),(5,2,6)]
list(gen_stream(59,precipitation_days,day_extractor)) #59: January and February to limit output
[0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

precipitation_days format is following: (d,m,mm), where d - day in month, m - month, mm - precipitation in millimeters
So, in example:

```
(3,1,4) # January,3 precipitation: 4 mm
(5,2,6) # February,5 precipitation: 6 mm
```

Extractor passed as optional third parameter with default value - lambda function that handles (position, value) pairs like in first example.

This is where the questions begin

**Question 1**
Can I replace

```
    try:
        current_extracted_record = extractor(next(sorted_iterator))
    except StopIteration:
        current_extracted_record = None
```

with default value for the function **next** instead of catching the exception StopIteration by using one line of code

```
current_extracted_record = extractor(next((sorted_iterator), None))
```

will it always work correctly in other situations?

**Question 2** How can this part be replaced by using default value for the method **next()** and loop **while** instead of the loop **for**. In theory, the code should be shorter.

```
    for i in iterable:
        if current_extracted_record:
            if i == current_extracted_record[0]:
                try:
                    yield current_extracted_record[1]
                    current_extracted_record = extractor(next(sorted_iterator))
                except StopIteration:
                    current_extracted_record = None
            else:
                yield 0
        else:
            yield 0
```

**Question 3** This may seem like an idiotic question, but as I understand it, the extractor does not have an index. Then what do the numbers in square brackets mean?

```
current_extracted_record[0] 
current_extracted_record[1]
```

Thanks if you can help.

*I apologize for the 3 questions in the thread, but it seems to me that they describe the same problem in different details.*

**Answer (Question1&Question2)**

```
def gen_stream(total, sorted_iterable, extractor=lambda x: x):
    elem_iter = iter(map(extractor, sorted_iterable))
    pos, val = next(elem_iter, (None, None))
    cnt = 0
    while total is None or cnt < total:
        if cnt == pos:
            yield val
            pos, val = next(elem_iter, (None, None))
        else:
            yield 0
        cnt += 1
```

Comment: Each question here should be focused on a single question / problem, not a list of questions.

Comment: @Prophet Sorry, but question 1 and 2 are pretty much the same thing. Question 3 is just an explanation for the second. I agree with question 4 - it is separate. Should I delete it?

Comment: I'm not a moderator here, but this question may be simply closed because of this. It's your decision what to do

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1**

No, `extractor(next(sorted_iterator, None))` will fail if `next` returns `None` and `extractor` can't handle it. For example your `day_extractor` can't (it crashes) and the default identity extractor doesn't return a pair of index and value, so the *later* code will fail.

**Question 2**

You *can* make the whole thing shorter by mapping `extractor` on `sorted_iterable` and asking for `next` values of *that*:

```
def gen_stream(total, sorted_iterable, extractor=lambda x: x):
    specials = map(extractor, sorted_iterable)
    iterable = count() if total is None else range(total)
    current_extracted_record = next(specials, None)
    for i in iterable:
        if current_extracted_record and i == current_extracted_record[0]:
            yield current_extracted_record[1]
            current_extracted_record = next(specials, None)
        else:
            yield 0
```

Since you don't have negative indexes, we can also use `[-1]` instead of `None` to shorten the inner `if` condition (or with really anything not in `count()`, e.g., `[None]`). And let me rename a bit as well.

```
def gen_stream(total, sorted_iterable, extractor=lambda x: x):
    specials = map(extractor, sorted_iterable)
    indexes = count() if total is None else range(total)
    next_special = next(specials, [-1])
    for i in indexes:
        if i == next_special[0]:
            yield next_special[1]
            next_special = next(specials, [-1])
        else:
            yield 0
```

**Question 3**

`current_extracted_record` is what the extractor returned, i.e., the next special (index, value) *pair*. Which has indexes 0 and 1.

Comment: Will code like this work with an infinite generator? Will there be memory problems in this case?

Comment: Yes. No. It's all lazy. Try it :-)

Comment: could you compare my answer with others in this thread?

Answer (score 2):

I would reduce the entire function to

```
from itertools import count, islice, chain, repeat


def gen_stream(sorted_iterable, *, extractor=lambda x: x, total=None):
    itr = chain(map(extractor, sorted_iterable), repeat(None))

    current = next(itr)
    for i in islice(count(), total):
        if current is None or i != current[0]:
            yield 0
        else:
            yield current[1]
            current = next(itr)
```

We create an iterator whose elements are the return values of `extractor` applied to the original iterable, followed by `None` for as long as necessary. No need to check for `StopIteration` explicitly.

If `total` is `None`, then `islice(count(), total)` is equivalent to `count()`; otherwise, it's equivalent to `range(total)`.

---

Alternatively,

```
def gen_stream(sorted_iterable, *, extractor=lambda x: x, total=None):
    def stream():
        pos = 0
        for new_pos, value in map(extractor, sorted_iterable):
            yield from repeat(0, new_pos - pos)
            yield value
            pos = new_pos + 1
    yield from islice(chain(stream(), repeat(0)), total)
```

The internal generator will patch the gaps with 0s, then the final `yield from` can produce the desired stream.

---

In each case, I made the two optional arguments keyword-only, since I kept typing `gen_stream([...], 9)`, accidentally setting the extractor instead of the total. You can keep your original signature, or some other variation, if you like.

Comment: Neat idea to slice count. No need to repeat `None`, though. And you could use my better-default trick as well.

Comment: Yeah, the alternate version was just all sorts of broken. I think the newer version is working correctly.

Comment: Yes, new new one looks good :-). Still dislike the `repeat(None)` of the first, though. That suggests that you might repeatedly read from that, which you don't. So it's misleading/confusing. I'd replace it with `[None]`.

Comment: You *might* repeatedly read from it, if you ask for more more elements than the iterable will provide. It just converts all the "if an exception is raised, return 0" cases with "if the iterator yields `None`, return 0" cases.

Comment: No, once you have a `None`, you never read from it again. You then keep going into the `if` branch, only yielding zeros. You don't ever go into the `else` branch with its `next(itr)` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is asking if the two-argument form of `next` can help you simplify the code:

```
try:
    current_extracted_record = extractor(next(sorted_iterator))
except StopIteration:
    current_extracted_record = None
```

My answer is a sort of maybe. You can't just put in `None` as the second argument to the existing `next` call because there's no guarantee the `extractor` function can handle being given `None` as an input. The current code won't ever pass `None` in to `extractor`, and while `None` is supported by the default NOOP function, other extractor functions (like your day index one) may not be happy about it. Now, you could change the specification of the main function to require that any extractor support `None` (e.g. by passing it through unchanged), but without that you'd need at least a little bit of complexity to handle `None`. Here's how I'd do it:

```
raw_record = next(sorted_iterator, None)
current_extracted_record = extractor(raw_record) if raw_record is not None else None
```

Your second question asks if you can simplify your loop somehow. I don't think the loop itself has any obvious simplifications available (using a `while` instead of `for` is probably not productive), but you can simplify the two `if` statements you have into a single one, since they both do the same thing if the condition is not met (`yield 0`):

```
for i in iterable:
    if current_extracted_record and i == current_extracted_record[0]: # combine both conditions
        yield current_extracted_record[1]
        raw_record = next(sorted_iterator, None)      # might as well use the code from q1 here
        current_extracted_record = extractor(raw_record) if raw_record is not None else None
    else:
        yield 0
```

As for your third question, I'm not sure why you think `current_extracted_record` won't be indexable. It's a 2-tuple, so there are always going to be two items that can be accessed. In the code, they're an index and a value. With the default `extractor`, they're directly from the input list (e.g. `(4, 111)`), but with a custom extractor they can be computed from that original value, rather than being directly a part of it (e.g. the `acc` and `x[2]` values produced by your `day_extractor` function).

Comment: Not quite safe, consider for example `gen_stream(5, [None], lambda _: (2, 'aha!'))` (i.e., you might confuse a *given* `None` with your default one).