# Stream generator. Limitations of output in an infinite iterator

Tags: python, function, loops, iterator

I'm trying to figure out how an iterator works with this example:

There is the function that produces stream generator for given iterable object (list, generator, etc) whose elements contain position and value and sorted by order of apperance.
Stream generator is equal to initial stream (without position), gaps filled with zeroes.

```
from itertools import count

def gen_stream(total, sorted_iterable, extractor=lambda x: x):
    sorted_iterator = iter(sorted_iterable)
    iterable = count() if total is None else range(total)
    try:
        current_extracted_record = extractor(next(sorted_iterator))
    except StopIteration:
        current_extracted_record = None
    for i in iterable:
        if current_extracted_record:
            if i == current_extracted_record[0]:
                try:
                    yield current_extracted_record[1]
                    current_extracted_record = extractor(next(sorted_iterator))
                except StopIteration:
                    current_extracted_record = None
            else:
                yield 0
        else:
            yield 0
```

[Here are other, most likely, more advanced options for writing this function.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68990208/stream-generator-using-an-iterator-in-detail)

For example:

```
gen = gen_stream(9,[(4,111),(7,12)])
list(gen) 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 111, 0, 0, 12, 0] # first element has zero index, so 111 located on fifth position, 12 located on 8th position
```

This function also support custom position-value extractor for more advanced cases, e.g.

```
def day_extractor(x):
    months = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    acc = sum(months[:x[1] - 1]) + x[0] - 1
    return acc, x[2]
```

```
precipitation_days = [(3,1,4),(5,2,6)]
list(gen_stream(59,precipitation_days,day_extractor)) #59: January and February to limit output
[0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

precipitation_days format is following: (d,m,mm), where d - day in month, m - month, mm - precipitation in millimeters
So, in example:

```
(3,1,4) # January,3 precipitation: 4 mm
(5,2,6) # February,5 precipitation: 6 mm
```

Extractor passed as optional third parameter with default value - lambda function that handles (position, value) pairs like in first example.

**Question 4**

Following the example of this statement

```
print(list(gen_stream(59, precipitation_days, day_extractor)))
```

How to add examples with **None** (instead 59) but limit output using the loop **for**.

**Answer**

```
gen = gen_stream(None, [(4, 111), (7, 12)])
print([next(gen) for _ in range(20)], '\n')
```

Comment: Is anything above "Question 4" different than in your previous question, or do I need to read it again?

Comment: And I don't understand question 4. Why would you want to do that, and what for loop do you mean?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode it is obvious that this `print(list(gen_stream(None, precipitation_days, day_extractor)))` statement  does not stop by itself. I would like to somehow add an interruption condition to it

Comment: So... that doesn't really warrant that entire huge preamble then, does it? You could just ask about `print(list(itertools.count()))`?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode sorry. I was just asked to split the original post into two topics. And did it not quite correctly.